# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que según como empieza una celda me devuelva un valor en otra celda?

Tags: sql-server

Pendiente de borrar esta pregunta por motivos profesionales

Comment: Y el `FROM`? Dónde está?

Comment: De dónde quieres sacar ese campo fichero? qué es `t`? No lo sabemos

Comment: En el from no puede haber un case. Tal vez, si te explicas mejor, entendamos mejor que queres hacer...

Comment: Considera tomar un curso básico de Bases de Datos. Has hecho muchas preguntas que demuestran una falta de comprensión básica de las mismas.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores en la consulta.
El primero es que utilizas "t" como alias pero no lo declaras como tal, debería ser

`from [dbo].[BBDD_LineaDeNegocioPrueba] as t`

Fíjate en la t final

En segundo lugar la evaluación `Left(t.Fichero, 4) = 'LDA_COCHES'` siempre será falsa, puede que te sirva `Left(t.Fichero, 10) = 'LDA_COCHES'` y así con el resto.

En tercer lugar el `from [dbo].[BBDD_LineaDeNegocioPrueba] as t` va al final de la sentencia.

```
Select t.Fichero, 
CASE
WHEN Left(t.Fichero, 10) = 'LDA_COCHES' then 'COCHES'
WHEN Left(t.Fichero, 9) = 'LDA_HOGAR' then 'HOGAR'
WHEN Left(t.Fichero, 9) = 'LDA_MOTOS' then 'MOTOS'
END AS division
, Right(t.Fichero, 8) as fecha
from [dbo].[BBDD_LineaDeNegocioPrueba] t
```

Comment: El error me dice que está en CASE

Comment: Si, en mi respuesta olvidé una coma después de `t.Fichero`